# subtract 2 day current date in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am usig azure data factory and basically I need to add a dynamic content (date function) to do this:

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can do the below using [Logical Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#logical-functions)

```
@equals(formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-2),'yyyy-MM-dd'),formatDateTime(activity('Your Metadata Activity Name').output.lastmodifieddate,'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Comment: I wanted to use addDays() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just addDays() function to get date differences. Detailed document on Azure Data Factory expressions and function is available : [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions)
I used `@{formatDateTime(convertfromutc(addDays(utcNow(),-6),'Eastern Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd' )}` Here I wanted to get 6 days old date (from current date).

Answer (score 0):

If Date contains timestamp then you should try below code.

```html
@string(addhours('2022-08-03 06:20:51',-2, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'))
```